# Complicated regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace

I need to make a regex and/or PHP code to replace text like this :

```
{Hello|Hi} sir.
{How are you?|How are you doing?}
```

Into :

```
<select id="q1">
    <option value="hello">Hello</option>
    <option value="hi">Hi</option>
</select>
sir.
<select id="q2">
    <option value="how_are_you">How are you?</option>
    <option value="how_are_you_doing">How are you doing?</option>
</select>
```

While the "value" is the text with spaces replaced by _ and symbols removed.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot some info.
I already have a working regex:

```
{([a-zA-Zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ\-\|]{2,})}
```

But for replacing all the stuff, `$1` only returns the last letter...
I've also tried using `strpos` and `substr`, but nothing worked.

Comment: OP, can we see an initial attempt first? I think that might be the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: I have an answer if this gets opened back up...

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for this. Show what you've tried, and this question may be reopened, and I can show you how to do it using php functions

Comment: I've edited the question, adding what I've tried.

Comment: Not just the regex, but your whole attempt basically

Comment: I have a working example using `substr` and `strpos` and some others

Comment: guess you don't want an answer...

Comment: @ElefantPhace go ahead ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$q1 = "{Hello|Hi} sir.";
$q2 = "{How are you?|How are you doing?}";

$q = substr($q1, 1, strpos($q1,'}')-1);
$q_end = substr($q1, strpos($q1, '}')+2);
$parts = explode('|',$q);

echo "<select name=\"q1\">\n";
foreach($parts as $part){
    echo "\t<option value=\"".strtolower($part)."\">$part</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
echo $q_end . "\n";

$q = substr($q2, 1, strpos($q2, '}')-1);
$parts = explode('|',$q);

echo "<select name=\"q2\">\n";
foreach($parts as $part){
    echo "\t<option value=\"".strtolower(substr(str_replace(' ','_',$part),0,strlen($part)-1))."\">$part</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
```

output:

```
<select name="q1">
    <option value="hello">Hello</option>
    <option value="hi">Hi</option>
</select>
sir.
<select name="q2">
    <option value="how_are_you">How are you?</option>
    <option value="how_are_you_doing">How are you doing?</option>
</select>
```

Of course depending on how and where you're getting your questions from and in what format you'll have to fix accordingly. But this gives you a starting point and an idea of how to proceed